# Using Like functions for search

Tags: vb.net

I am searching through my data grid view.  My search variable picks data from the Cell, matches with search string and reports.  This is perfect.
I need to make it work so that if use wants to search say "John", block containing "John Smith" should be matched.  At the moment I have to use "John Smith" completely.

Please advise how to do it.  My code is shown below.

```
Do While vrTotalRows > vrLoopCntr
            vrPickFromGrid = UCase(DataGridView1.Item(0, vrLoopCntr).Value)
            If vrPickFromGrid = UCase(txtFind.Text) Then 'Found
                DataGridView1.Rows(vrLoopCntr).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue
            End If
            vrPickFromGridC2 = UCase(DataGridView1.Item(1, vrLoopCntr).Value)
            If vrPickFromGridC2 = UCase(txtFind.Text) Then 'Found
                DataGridView1.Rows(vrLoopCntr).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue
            End If
            vrLoopCntr = vrLoopCntr + 1
        Loop
```

Comment: Ugh - the style used for your code has vb6 written all over it.  Much of what you're doing is backwards now.

Comment: What do you suggest to make it vb.net code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use [String.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dy85x1sa%28VS.80%29.aspx)

```
If vrPickFromGrid = UCase(txtFind.Text) Then
```

becomes :

```
If vrPickFromGrid.Contains(UCase(txtFind.Text)) Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.Contains(...)`.